# zero vector and vector space question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the set of all ordered pairs of real numbers $(u_1, u_2)$ with $u_2 > 0$. Consider the following addition and scalar multiplication operations on $u = (u_1, u_2)$ and $v = (v_1, v_2)$: $$u + v = (u_1 + v_1 + 2, 6u_2 v_2), \quad ku = (ku_1, ku_2)$$

Use the above operations for the following parts.

(a)     Compute $u + v$ for $u = (-1, 7)$ and $v = (1, 3)$.

(b)     If the set $V$ satisfies Axiom 4 of a vector space (the existence of a zero vector), what would be the zero vector?

(c)     If $u = (3, 5)$, what would be the negative of the vector $u$ referred to in Axiom 5 of a vector space?
(Don't forget to use your answer to part (b) here!)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If $u+v=u$ for all $u$, then $u_1+v_1+2=u_1$ and $6u_2v_2=u_2$ for all $u_1,u_2$, with $u_2>0$. This is equivalent to $v_1=-2$ and $v_2=1/6$. So, if a vector is going to be the zero, it should be $(-2,1/6)$.

Comment: I think you can attempt part (a) and show the work here.  For part (b) and (c), at least you can tell us what Axioim 4 and 5 are :)